# What relation have the Markov Property with Queueing Theory?

Tags: stochastic-processes, soft-question, exponential-distribution

What relation have the Markov Property of Exponential Distribution, with Queueing Theory?
i need to know the relation between [Markov Property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_property)
and queuying theory

Comment: (Since you had hid that other question you just posted) If you don't want downvotes on your questions, just make sure that you show some effort and work in your question. Asking a question without showing any work sounds like a 'Please do my homework for me' quesrion, which is really frowned upon in this community. So: show some effort! Show some work! This will help us identify exactly where you are getting stuck and why, and thus help us provide specific pointers, tips, and hints, and make you best learn how to solve the problems yourself.

Comment: yeah thank you for the tip i understand that (i answer my own question here only after read well the definitions thats why i think that is not a big deal the Q) but for example [ook this questio](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/511448/what-theory-should-validate-about-the-mean-of-1000-sample-means) i write a lot, after more than 3 edits, i paste all the simulations and still downvotes i really feel bad and without energy to be an active user. But at least in math stack exchange are better than cross validated...

Comment: [even downvote my answers](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/499983/alguem-me-ajuda-em-exercicio-com-lista-em-python/499985#499985) so i dont know i cant be perfect mods told about my code needs perfomance and more details explained the code thats why the downvotes but i cant do that i have a job i have very few time for create the perfect answers or the long answer. so thats why i feel insecure posting Q/A maybe is better keep for myself.

Comment: For that first one... not sure what is going on there ... it could be that you received downvotes for your original posts, and doing edits after that may not take those downvotes waway since the people who downvoted may not have seen your later edits.

Comment: For the second one: that looks like an answer without any further explanation ... some people may have felt like you did someone else's HW, and that in doing so you encourage people coming to this forum to have their HW done, rather than discourage them. This forum is really more for *explaining*, *learning*, and *understanding*, not just for 'get me the correct answer'.

Comment: Finally, please do not feel discouraged or intimidated to use this forum to get help. It will take everybody some time to learn how to ask a good question or give a good answer :)

Comment: 1)is a sum of means and sum of standart deviation of 1000 rolling dies. well i had downvotes but the new edit change the reason of closed question and i have more downvotes after that. but i gotcha i need to be more didactic here.
2) oh my god i didnt know that kind of reception how i know more about the users behaviour of stack exchange? i had to left my university so maybe this a good free place for improve/show my academic skills. is complicate when to be didactic and when to be specific. and thk for the advice. :)

Comment: Hey, sorry to hear you had to leave your university, but I commend you for trying to self-learn!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's related with theory of queues from its definition if we read the Queueing Theory and Markov Property whats about:.

You can think of a queue or a queue node as almost a black box. Jobs or "clients" arrive in the queue, possibly wait some time, take some time to process, and then exit the queue.

[image]

However, the tail node is not a pure black box, as some information about the interior of the tail node is needed. The queue has one or more "servers", each of which can pair with an arriving job until its departure, after which that server is free to pair with another arriving job.

[image]

In this way the markov property is related to the theory of queues, we are talking about a node that passes from one state to another without having memory of the previous events only of the present and the future state.
[image]

$P(X_n+1 | X_n )$

[image]

Markov processes use an exponential variable because no matter how much time has elapsed since the last movement in the distribution, the time until the next movement only depends on the state of the process (and not on the waiting time).

edit: i had to solve this myself after learn a various of definitions.
nobody understand my question and was closed cause not enought information and additional context.